# Не работает функция getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript

```
function set() {
            var sendMess = document.getElementById("send-mess");
            var styleIdSendMess = window.getComputedStyle(sendMess, null);
            var displaySendMess = styleIdSendMess.display;
            alert(displaySendMess);       
    }
```

Выскакивает ошибка:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данного элемента на момент запуска функции не существует, дождитесь загрузки страницы, используйте window.load или поставьте скрипт ниже необходимого элемента

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'` - переменная sendMess у вас не является объектом `Element`. Советую добавить строку вывода в консоль и смотреть, что там во время ошибки:

```
function set() {
    var sendMess = document.getElementById("send-mess");
    console.log(sendMess);
    var styleIdSendMess = window.getComputedStyle(sendMess, null);
    var displaySendMess = styleIdSendMess.display;
    alert(displaySendMess);       
}
```

Но правильней было бы добавить проверку:

```
if (sendMess.constructor && sendMess.constructor.name === 'HTMLElement') {
    // get what you want
}
```